# UNIX Awk division giving 0

Tags: unix, awk

I'm new to UNIX so i may be missing something obvious here but i am trying to divide two variables, and getting 0.00 as the output.
Here is the problematic part of the code:

```
echo $reviewsum
echo $noofreviews
av=$(awk -v sum="${reviewsum}" -v no="${noofreviews}" 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f", sum/no; exit(0)}')
echo $av
```

Output:

```
62

20
0.00
```

My variables are created in the same script and are found correctly (shown by the echo), so result should be 62 / 20 which is 3.1, but the output gives 0.00 instead, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `gawk` instead of whatever version `awk` might be.

Comment: Don't you find it odd that there's a blank line between `62` and `20` in your output? Change your first 2 echo lines to `echo "<$reviewsum>" | cat -v` and `echo "<$noofreviews>" | cat-v` so we can see what they **really** contain. FWIW I'd put money on the `62` actually being output by some other command before the section of code you show us and the `echo $reviewsum` is outputing a blank line.

Comment: Interestingly i have tried this line `av=$(awk 'BEGIN{printf("%0.2f", "$reviewsum" / "$noofreviews")}')` and it returns a division by zero error, will follow your suggestion and report back now @EdMorton

Comment: `62
<>
<      20>
awk: division by zero
 source line number 1`

Comment: @jsc, in your comment one hour ago, your awk command body is in single quotes, so the shell variables are not getting substituted. So you have two strings that get converted to zero in the numeric context of division. It's equivalent to `awk 'BEGIN {printf "%f", 0/0}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `62` shown at the start of the output you posted in your question is being output by some command earlier in your code that you haven't shown us, not by `echo $reviewsum`, and `$reviewsum` contains a NULL string.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with whitespace for both variables. Is there a way for me to just extract the numbers from them, maybe by outputting them to text files and reading in just numbers?

Comment: To be clear: `reviewsum` is empty, **THAT** is your problem. `noofreviews` does have a leading blank char but awk will ignore that and just use the number so that is not a problem. So the question you are asking in your comment above has zero relevance to the code/problem in your question and if you're asking in relation to some OTHER problem then you should post a new question with the details of that problem.

Comment: you're correct! the 62 was output by a different command which i have now rectified, but there is still the issue of a 6 whitespaces before the 20

Comment: There is no issue with having 6 whitespaces before the 20 - awk will just ignore them.

Comment: still getting division by zero. cat -v gave <62> for the reviewsum and <      20> for the noofreviews

Comment: From the code in your question using awk variables set with `-v`, or the code you put in the comment under your question where you're invalidly trying to use shell variables inside an awk script? I assume the latter as that is trying to dive by a constant string `"$noofreviews"` which has the numeric value zero. The code in your question will work. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Took me a while to understand that comment! The syntax in the first one did make it work though. Thanks for your help Ed, you've managed to solve quite a few problems with this one.

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me ! :

```
elmehdi@elmehdi-MS-7917:/var/www/OCar$ reviewsum=62;noofreviews=20;av=$(awk -v sum="${reviewsum}" -v no="${noofreviews}" 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f", sum/no; exit(0)}');echo $av
3.10
```

which linux distribution are you using ?

Comment: Im using terminal on OS X el capitan

Comment: There is nothing about Linux in the question, but it is tagged [tag:unix].

Comment: @jsc This line on el capitan gives the correct result for me too.